# WCF operation contract : Optional Parameter Support?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF operation contract as below . I have a requirement wherein this operation contract should have an extra parameter to handle a client scenario. But I cannot change the operation contract signature as its been used by various other clients as well.

As far as I have checked operation contract in WCF cannot have optional parameters . Any other suggestions ?

```
Code GetDataElementes(String MyType, String MyUniqueID, out DataTable dTableOut);
```

Answer (score 2):

WCF operations can have optional parameters. Any parameter that is nullable is optional. Clients can pass null, or they can leave out the parameter in the XML that they are sending.

This feature is important for backwards compatibility.

Just create one method with all parameters and handle the case that some arguments are null.

Regarding out parameters: It's usually better style to create a DTO class and return an instance of that. All out parameters become properties of that class.

Comment: Good recommendation on using DTOs instead of `out` parameters.  DTOs fit better with the SOA concept (IMO), whereas `out` parameters are specific to C# and more of a programming concept in general.

Answer (score 0):

Method names on services have to be unique. You can use either diffrent names for your methods or set the `Name` property of your `OperationContract` like this:

```
[OperationContract(Name = "GetDataElementes")]
Code GetDataElementes(String MyType, String MyUniqueID, out DataTable dTableOut);

[OperationContract(Name = "GetDataElementes2")]
Code GetDataElementes();//Or with different parameters
```

Also have a look at [this](http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2006/09/21/Overloading-Methods-in-WCF.aspx) may helpful.